# Unable to obtain the correct product of numbers when used with Math.pow()

Tags: java, recursion

I was trying to write a recursive function which gets a string and returns the integer form of it. I know that this can be done easily in Java using `Integer.parseInt`. This is a part of an exercise I am doing.

For the following code, when I enter "963" as the input, it returns the output as "6291". So, i checked if the array was getting passed properly and it was.

To check the multiplication, I split and printed the product each time, which gave 5700, 540 and 51, which correctly sum up to 6291. (which actually should have been 900 + 60 + 3 = 963). I'm unable to figure out what is wrong in my program.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
class RecConvert
{
    static double i=0;
    static double sum=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader B = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input = B.readLine();
        int number = RecursiveConvert(input);
        System.out.println("The number is "+number);
    }

    static int RecursiveConvert(String input)
    {
        char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
        if(i < charArray.length)
            {
                sum = sum + (charArray[(int)i]) * ( (double)Math.pow(10.0,charArray.length-i-1) );
                i++;
                return RecursiveConvert(input);
            }
        else
            return (int)sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem `(charArray[(int)i])`. You're multiplying a `char` with a double. `Character.getNumericValue(charArray[(int)i])` will solve it.

Comment: I changed it to `sum = sum + (double)(charArray[(int)i]) * ( (double)Math.pow(10.0,charArray.length-i-1) );` but it still returns 6291.

Comment: Check my answer for what to do. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but it still returns 6291. :(

Comment: sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(charArray[(int)i]) * ( (double)Math.pow(10.0,charArray.length-i-1) ); -- this works fine for me.